# Filtering objects in underscore

Tags: javascript, loops, filter, underscore.js, each

I'm trying to create a `filterObject` mixin in underscore. It's not going quite well, is there something I'm missing?

```
_.mixin({
  filterObject: function(collection, fn){
    var n = []
    _.each(collection, function(value, key){
      var decider = fn(value, key)
      if(decider){
        var temp = {}
        temp[key] = value
        n.push(temp)
      }
    })
    return _.extend.apply(null, n);
  }
})

var actionsFlags = {
  "wallpaper": {
    "images": true,
    "queue": false,
  },
  "notify":{
    "message": true,
    "open": true,
    "queue": false,
  },
}

var requiredFlags = _.filterObject(actionsFlags, function(flags){
  return _.filterObject(flags, function(flag){
    return flag
  })
})
```

I just need a way to have the `actionsFlags` object where it only contains props equal to `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 1.7 the [**_.pick**](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) function can take an iteratee which can be used instead of filterObject:

```
var requiredFlags = _.mapObject(actionsFlags, function(flags){
    return _.pick(flags, function(flag){
        return flag === true;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, just have to `mapObject` then `filterObject`.

```
  var requiredFlags = _.mapObject(actionsFlags, function(flags){
    return _.filterObject(flags, function(flag){
      return flag
    })
  })
```

Comment: You can replace that call to _.filterObject with a call to underscore's _.pick which from version 1.7 can take an iteratee.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! If you want submit an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it using the open source project jinqJs http://www.jinqJs.com

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tford/v1naL6kp/1/)

```
var result = jinqJs().from(actionsFlags).select( function(row) {
var ret = {};
for(var o in row)
{
    ret[o] = {};   
    for(var i in row[o])
    {
        if (row[o][i])
            ret[o][i] = true;
    }

}

return ret;
```

});